# Adding two functions together to make one value?

Tags: javascript, function, blackjack

Hello amazing people of StackOverflow,
                                      I am trying to make a blackjack game using javascript. In my code I have two functions. These functions deal out a first card value when "deal" has been pressed and deals out a second card value when "Hit" has been pressed. How would I go about adding these two functions to add the value of both cards, so I can test if the player has gone over the value of 21? I appreciate the time you have spent reading this, thank you! Here is my code:

```js
var score = 0;

var deck = ["ace", "ace", "ace", "ace", 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, "jack", "jack", "jack", "jack", "queen", "queen", "queen", "queen", "king", "king", "king", "king"];

function deal() {
  var random = deck[Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length)];
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = random;
}

function hit() {
  var random2 = deck[Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length)];
  document.getElementById('result2').innerHTML = random2;
}

var time = new Date();
document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = time.toDateString();
```

```css
#deal {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50px;
  height: 35px;
  top: 500px;
  left: 500px;
  background-color: silver;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-style: ridge;
}
#hit {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50px;
  height: 35px;
  top: 500px;
  border-style: ridge;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
body {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  background: url("http://corporate.fortuna2000.be/imgs/background/red_poker3_xl.jpg");
}
#ace {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
#time {
  position: absolute;
  top: 590px;
  right: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="result2"></div>
<div id="time"></div>
<input type="button" value="deal" onclick="deal()" id="deal">
<input type="button" value="hit" onclick="hit()" id="hit">
```

Comment: I guess you need another function that gets the total value of the cards in a hand and checks if it's `<= 21`.

Comment: and another line of code to remove cards from the deck...

Comment: When you `hit` you're supposed to add an additional card, not replace the card.

Comment: @softwarenewbie7331—that can be done in the same line as `var random …` using *splice*. The *deck* array needs to be reinitialised on each new game though (but the OP hasn't got that far yet…).

Comment: You need a function that converts a card name to a value. It can get the `innerHTML` of all the DIVs, convert their values, and add them up to see if it's over 21.

Comment: @RobG i know. the op probably didn't notice.. im thinking if i should give the complete solution or just the part he asked about

Comment: @softwarenewbie7331focus on the question at hand. Bring conversation about overall solution somewhere else e.g. email, temp chat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the number value total working, but I didn't get the suit, dealer, or turns done yet. Since you requested for only the former, this should suffice.

I used splice to remove played cards from the deck, renamed the cards so they were easier to parse (I used radix 16 (hexidecimal) so 'a'=10 and 'b'=11) the number values.

```js
var score = [];
var status;
var deck = ['c-b', 'h-b', 'd-b', 's-b', 'c-2', 'h-2', 'd-2', 's-2', 'c-3', 'h-3', 'd-3', 's-3', 'c-4', 'h-4', 'd-4', 's-4', 'c-5', 'h-5', 'd-5', 's-5', 'c-6', 'h-6', 'd-6', 's-6', 'c-7', 'h-7', 'd-7', 's-7', 'c-8', 'h-8', 'd-8', 's-8', 'c-9', 'h-9', 'd-9', 's-9', 'ct-a', 'ht-a', 'dt-a', 'st-a', 'cj-a', 'hj-a', 'dj-a', 'sj-a', 'cq-a', 'hq-a', 'dq-a', 'sq-a', 'ck-a', 'hk-a', 'dk-a', 'sk-a'];
var handCards = document.getElementById('hand');
var handScore = document.getElementById('score');
var hitMe = document.getElementById('hit');

function deal(x) {
  x = parseInt(x, 10);
  if (!x) {
    var y = 1;
  } else {
    y = x;
  }

  console.log('y: ' + y);
  var suit = '';
  var hole = 0;
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < y; i++) {
    var idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length);
    var card = deck[idx];
    deck.splice(idx, 1);
    suit = sortCard(card);
    console.log('card: ' + card);
    var num = card.split('-').pop();
    if (num === 'b') {
      hole++;
    }
    console.log('hole: ' + hole);
    console.log('num: ' + num);
    var val = parseInt(num, 16);
    console.log('val: ' + val);
    score.push(val);
    console.log('score: ' + score[i]);
    total = score.reduceRight(function(a, b) {
      return a + b;
    });
    console.log('total: ' + total);
  }

  handCards.value = suit;
  handScore.value = total;
  if (total > 21 && hole < 1) {
    status = 'bust';
  } else if (total > 21 && hole > 0) {
    hole = hole - 1;
    total = total - 10;
    status = 'prompt';
  } else if (total < 21) {
    status = 'prompt';
  } else if (total === 21) {
    status = 'stay';
  } else return false;

  session(status);
}
var sortCard = function(card) {
  var face = [];
  for (var j = card.length; j < 0; j--) {
    var ch = card.charAt(j);
    console.log('ch' + j + ': ' + ch);
    switch (ch) {
      case 'b':
        kind = 'Ace of ';
        break;
      case 'k':
        kind = 'King of ';
        break;
      case 'q':
        kind = 'Queen of ';
        break;
      case 'j':
        kind = 'Jack of ';
        break;
      case '2':
        kind = 'Two of ';
        break;
      case '3':
        kind = 'Three of ';
        break;
      case '4':
        kind = 'Four of ';
        break;
      case '5':
        kind = 'Five of ';
        break;
      case '6':
        kind = 'Six of ';
        break;
      case '7':
        kind = 'Seven of ';
        break;
      case '8':
        kind = 'Eight of ';
        break;
      case '9':
        kind = 'Nine of ';
        break;
      case 't':
        kind = 'Ten of ';
        break;
      case 'c':
        kind = 'Clubs';
        break;
      case 'h':
        kind = 'Hearts';
        break;
      case 'd':
        kind = 'Diamonds';
        break;
      case 's':
        kind = 'Spades';
        break;
      case '0', '-', 'a', '1':
        break;
    }
    face.push(kind);
    console.log('face: ' + face);
  }
  suit = face.join();
  return suit;
}

function session(status) {
  var dTotal = 0;
  var msg = document.getElementById('msg');
  var hit = document.getElementById('hit');
  var stay = document.getElementById('stay');
  if (status === 'bust') {
    msg.value = total + " Busted!";
    hit.setAttribute('disabled', true);
  } else if (status === 'prompt') {
    msg.value = total + " Stay or Hit?";
  } else if (status === 'stay') {
    msg.value = 'Dealer has ' + dTotal;
    hit.setAttribute('disabled', true);
  } else return false;
}



deal('2');
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: 400 16px/2"Trebuchet MS";
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0 solid transparent;
  outline: 0;
  text-indent: 0;
}
body {
  height: 100%; width: 100%; background: #000; color: #FFF; position: relative; text-align: center; font-variant: small-caps; background: url("http://corporate.fortuna2000.be/imgs/background/red_poker3_xl.jpg"); }
  #hit, #stay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 35px;
    border: 1px ridge #633;
    border-radius: 6px;
    top: 50%;
    background: #933;
  }
  #stay {
    left: 35%;
  }
  #hit {
    right: 35%;
  }
  input {
    line-height: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #F93;
    border-radius: 8px;
    bacground: #900;
    color: #F90;
  }
  #msg {
    line-height: 3;
    background: #600;
    color: #FC3;
    font-size: 2rem;
    border: 2px solid #FC3;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<input id="msg">
<br/>
<br/>
<label for="hand">Hand:</label>
<input id="hand">
<br/>
<br/>
<label for='score'>Score:</label>
<input id="score">
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Hit" id="hit" onclick="deal(1);return false;">
<input type="button" value="Stay" id="stay" onclick="session('stay');return false;">
```

Comment: Yes. This will do just fine. Thanks. :)

Comment: Have fun and if you finish the rest, could you post it, please?  I never got to finish my blackjack project in school and I'd like to see a fully functional one. ;)

Comment: Yup, it should be done in the next few days. Would you like me to post it here, or start another post?

Comment: I think it'll be more relevant if you post it here, good luck. :)

Comment: I am deeply sorry to use more of your time, but I can't seem to figure out how to compare dTotal and total to figure out who wins the round. I am a JS newbie and have a little trouble reading it.

Comment: No worries @hainerboy, `dTotlal` is *dealer's total score*, you should have a staggered sequence of events. I'll update the post to illustrate what I mean.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I mainly don't understand the session function. It looks like it is supposed to check the card values and "msg" who won. but i can't get it working so that it checks and stops the player from going over 21.

Comment: Sorry I got stuck creating the Dealer which is basically the same as the Player. Only problem is if you use `deal(x);` for Player and Dealer, the value for **both** hands are added together. The best thing to do is make Player a prototype with `deal(x)` as a method, then use prototype inheritance to create a new instance of Player and name it Dealer.

Comment: That makes sooo much sense! Thank you! :D

Comment: Im extremely confused about this whole thing. I don't understand your code and I am getting nowhere further than what was posted. If you could help me understand what all of it means, it would be much appreciated, if not, Thanks again. I'll keep trying .

Answer (score 1):

Here you go @zer00ne. It took a little longer than expected. Thanks for all the help before.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<title>casino game.</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  html {
box-sizing: border-box;
font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0 solid transparent;
outline: 0;
text-indent: 0;
}
body {
height: 100%; width: 100%; background: #000; color: #FFF; position: relative; text-align: center; font-variant: small-caps; background: url("http://corporate.fortuna2000.be/imgs/background/red_poker3_xl.jpg");
}

#hit, #stay, #reshuffle,#hit2,#hit3, #hit4, #deal{
position: absolute;
width: 50px;
height: 35px;
border: 1px ridge;
border-radius: 6px;
top: 90%;
background:;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
}
  #hit{
right: 35%;
    visibility: hidden;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
}
  #hit2{
    right: 35%;
    visibility: hidden;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
     }
     #hit3{
         right: 35%;
            visibility: hidden;
            font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
     }
     #hit4{
         right: 35%;
            visibility: hidden;
            font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
     }

 #stay {
 left: 35%;
     visibility: hidden;
     font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
 }

 input {
 line-height: 2;
 cursor: pointer;
 border: 1px solid #F93;
 border-radius: 8px;
 background: #900;
 color: white;
     font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
 }

 #msg{
 background:;
 color:#F93 ;
 border: 2px solid #FC3;
 border-radius: 8px;
     border-color: #F93;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 20px;
     height: 90px;
     width: 800px;
     font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
 }

   #deal{
        position: absolute;
        width: 100px;
        height: 35px;
        border: 1px ridge;
        border-radius: 6px;
        top: 50%;
        left: 635px;
        right:50%;
        visibility: visible;
        font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
    }

    #displayOne{
      position: fixed;
      left: 70px;
      top: 100px;
    }

    #displayTwo{
      position: absolute;
      left: 70px;
      top: 150px;
    }

    #displayThree{
      position: absolute;
      left: 70px;
      top: 200px;
      visibility: hidden;
    }

    #displayFour{
      position: absolute;
      left: 70px;
      top: 250px;
      visibility: hidden;
    }

    #label1{
      position: fixed;
      left: 0px;
      top: 100px;
    }

    #label2{
      position: absolute;
      left: 0px;
      top: 150px;
    }

    #label3{
      position: absolute;
      left: 0px;
      top: 200px;
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    #label4{
      position: absolute;
      left: 0px;
      top: 250px;
      visibility: hidden;
    }


    #reshuffle{
      width: 65px;
      height: 35px;
      left: 635px;
      right:50%;
      visibility: hidden;
      font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body onload="instruction(); ">

<input type="text" id="msg" readonly = "readonly">
<br>
<input type="text" id="displayOne" readonly="readonly">
<br>
<input type="text" id="displayTwo" readonly="readonly">
<br>
<input type="text" id="displayThree" readonly="readonly">
<br>
<input type="text" id="displayFour" readonly="readonly">
<br>
<br>
<div id="label1">
  <h3>card 1</h3>
</div>

<div id="label2">
  <h3>card 2 </h3>
</div>
<div id="label3">
  <h3>card 3</h3>
</div>
<div id="label4">
  <h3>card 4</div>
</div>
<div id="img1"></div>
<div id="img2"></div>
<div id="img3"></div>
<input type="button" value="Deal" id="deal"  onclick="deal(); displayOne.value=card1; displayTwo.value=card2;">
<input type="button" value="Hit" id="hit" onclick="add();">
<input type="button" value="Hit2" id="hit2" onclick="add2();">
<input type="button" value="Hit3" id="hit3" onclick="add3();">
<input type="button" value="Hit4" id="hit4" onclick="add4();">


<input type="button" value="Reshuffle" id="reshuffle" onclick="location.reload();">

<input type="button" value="Stay" id="stay" onclick="stay();">

<audio>
  <source src="cardPlace4.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio>

<script type="text/javascript">
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// beginning of Javascript /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function instruction(){
  alert("INSTRUCTIONS: Dealer will deal player two cards. You have the option to stay with those two cards or hit for an extra card. The goal is to get an added value of you cards closest to 21 without going over 21. If you stay, the dealer will deal itself two cards. If the dealer has a value more than the player, the dealer wins. If you deal a value equal to 21, the dealer will automatically count it as a win. If you hit and you get a value more than 21, the dealer will count it as an automatic loss.")
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// declaring variables //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var card = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];
var suits = ['diamonds', 'spades', 'hearts', 'clubs'];
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// player values ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var card1 = card[Math.floor(Math.random()*card.length)];
var card2 = card[Math.floor(Math.random()*card.length)];
var card3 = card[Math.floor(Math.random()*card.length)];
var card4 = card[Math.floor(Math.random()*card.length)];
var card5 = card[Math.floor(Math.random()*card.length)];
var card6 = card[Math.floor(Math.random()*card.length)];
var pTotal = card1 + card2;
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Dealer values /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var dCard1 = card[Math.floor(Math.random()*card.length)];
var dCard2 = card[Math.floor(Math.random()*card.length)];
var dCard3 = card[Math.floor(Math.random()*card.length)];
var dCard4 = card[Math.floor(Math.random()*card.length)];
var dCard5 = card[Math.floor(Math.random()*card.length)];
var dCard6 = card[Math.floor(Math.random()*card.length)];
var dTotal = dCard1 + dCard2;
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// player suits ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var suit1 = suits[Math.floor(Math.random()*suits.length)];
var suit2 = suits[Math.floor(Math.random()*suits.length)];
var suit3 = suits[Math.floor(Math.random()*suits.length)];
var suit4 = suits[Math.floor(Math.random()*suits.length)];
var suit5 = suits[Math.floor(Math.random()*suits.length)];
var suit6 = suits[Math.floor(Math.random()*suits.length)];

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// dealer suits /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var dSuit1 = suits[Math.floor(Math.random()*suits.length)];
var dSuit2 = suits[Math.floor(Math.random()*suits.length)];
var dSuit3 = suits[Math.floor(Math.random()*suits.length)];
var dSuit4 = suits[Math.floor(Math.random()*suits.length)];
var dSuit5 = suits[Math.floor(Math.random()*suits.length)];
var dSuit = suits[Math.floor(Math.random()*suits.length)];
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// end of variables/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////beginning of functions////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var deal = function(){

var dealt = card1 + card2;
msg.value = dealt;
document.getElementById('hit').style.visibility = 'visible';
document.getElementById('stay').style.visibility = 'visible';
document.getElementById('deal').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var add = function(){
  document.getElementById('hit').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  document.getElementById('hit2').style.visibility = 'visible';
  var hit = card1 + card2 + card3;
  var pTotal = hit;
  msg.value = hit;
if(hit > 21){
  var bet = 90;
  msg.value = "You have been dealt a total of " + hit + ". Automatic loss.";
  document.getElementById('hit').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  document.getElementById('hit2').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  document.getElementById('hit3').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  document.getElementById('hit4').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  document.getElementById('stay').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  document.getElementById('reshuffle').style.visibility = 'visible';

}

if(hit === 21){
  msg.value = hit + " Automatic Win!";
  document.getElementById('hit').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  document.getElementById('hit2').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  document.getElementById('hit3').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  document.getElementById('hit4').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  document.getElementById('stay').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  document.getElementById('reshuffle').style.visibility = 'visible';

}
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var add2 = function(){
  document.getElementById('hit2').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  document.getElementById('hit3').style.visibility = 'visible';
  var hit = card1 + card2 + card3 + card4;
  pTotal = hit;
  msg.value = hit;
  if(hit > 21){
    msg.value = "You have been dealt a total of " + hit + ". Automatic loss."
    document.getElementById('hit').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('hit2').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('hit3').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('hit4').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('stay').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('reshuffle').style.visibility = 'visible';




  }
  if(hit === 21){
    msg.value = "You have been Dealt a total of " + hit + ". Automatic win!" ;
    document.getElementById('hit').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('hit2').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('hit3').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('hit4').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('stay').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('reshuffle').style.visibility = 'visible';


}
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var add3 = function(){
  document.getElementById('hit3').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  document.getElementById('hit4').style.visibility = 'visible';
  var hit = card1 + card2 + card3 + card4 + card5;
  pTotal = hit;
  msg.value = hit;
  if(hit > 21){
    msg.value = "You have been dealt a total of " + hit + ". Automatic loss.";
    document.getElementById('hit').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('hit2').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('hit3').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('hit4').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('stay').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('reshuffle').style.visibility = 'visible';



}
  if(hit === 21){
    msg.value = "You have been Dealt a total of " + hit + ". Automatic win!";
    document.getElementById('hit').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('hit2').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('hit3').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('hit4').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('stay').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('reshuffle').style.visibility = 'visible';

}
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var add4 = function(){
  var hit = card1 + card2 + card3 + card4 + card5 + card6;
  pTotal = hit;
  msg.value = hit;
  if(hit > 21){
    msg.value = "You have been dealt a total of " + hit + ". Automatic loss.";
    document.getElementById('hit').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('hit2').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('hit3').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('hit4').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('stay').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('reshuffle').style.visibility = 'visible';



}
  if(hit === 21){
    msg.value = "You have been Dealt a total of " + hit + ". Automatic win!";
    document.getElementById('hit').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('hit2').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('hit3').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('hit4').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('stay').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('reshuffle').style.visibility = 'visible';

}
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function dDeal(){
  dDealt = dTotal;

}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function stay(){
  document.getElementById('hit').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  document.getElementById('hit2').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  document.getElementById('hit3').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  document.getElementById('hit4').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  document.getElementById('stay').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  document.getElementById('reshuffle').style.visibility = 'visible';

if(pTotal > dTotal){
    msg.value = "Player value: " + pTotal + " Dealer Value: " + dTotal + ". Player wins!";
  }
  if(dTotal > pTotal){
    msg.value = "Player value: " + pTotal + " Dealer Value: " + dTotal + ". dealer wins!";
  }
  if( pTotal === dTotal){
    msg.value = "'tis but a tie'.... Player value: " + pTotal + ". Dealer value: " + dTotal;
  }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// end of functions ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////End of Javascript////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
</script>

</body>
</html>
```